# Selecting the Value of a td in a table and populating elsewhere using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

Am working on an application whereby I have some values in a table,,when the user clicks on any number on the table am having a problem capturing the number selected and populate on a single input field on the 2 rows on the right side

**Markup Code**

```
 <!--Table on the left -->
    <div style="width: 140px; float: left;">
        <table id="table1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>6</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <!-- Rows on the right-->
    <div style="float: right;" >
        <input type="text" id="inp1" value="">
        <input type="text"   id="inp2"  value="">
        <input type="text"  id="inp3"  value="">
        <input type="text"  id="inp4"  value="">
        <input type="text"  id="inp5"  value="">
        <input type="text"  id="inp6"  value="">        
    </div>

    <div style="float: right;  margin-top: 5px;" >
        <input type="text" id="inp1" value="">
        <input type="text"   id="inp2"  value="">
        <input type="text"  id="inp3"  value="">
        <input type="text"  id="inp4"  value="">
        <input type="text"  id="inp5"  value="">
        <input type="text"  id="inp6"  value="">        
    </div>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
// code to read selected table row cell data (values).
        $("#table1").on('click',function(){
            var data = $('tr td');
            alert(data);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

First we name all input with unique `Ids` (note you can't have duplicate `Ids` so I've renamed the second row Ids from `inp7` onwards.

Then it's a matter of capturing the click event target element's number, and placing it in the input `value` attribute:

```js
// code to read selected table row cell data (values).
let currentInput = 1; //first input

$("#table1 td").on('click',function(event){
    let num = $(this).text(); //gets the number associated with the click
    $("#inp" + currentInput++).attr("value",num); //set it to input's value attribute
});

$("input").hover( function(event) {
    let num = $(this).attr("value");
    if (num) {
         $(this).css("backgroundColor","green");
         $("#table1 td").each(function() {
             if ($(this).text() === num) $(this).css("backgroundColor","green");
         });
    }   
}, function(event) {
    $(this).css("backgroundColor","white");
          $("#table1 td").each(function() {
 $(this).css("backgroundColor","white");
         });   
});
```

```css
td {
   border: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Table on the left -->
    <div style="width: 140px; float: left;">
        <table id="table1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>6</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <!-- Rows on the right-->
    <div style="float: right;" >
        <input type="text" id="inp1" value="">
        <input type="text"   id="inp2"  value="">
        <input type="text"  id="inp3"  value="">
        <input type="text"  id="inp4"  value="">
        <input type="text"  id="inp5"  value="">
        <input type="text"  id="inp6"  value="">        
    </div>

    <div style="float: right;  margin-top: 5px;" >
        <input type="text" id="inp7" value="">
        <input type="text"   id="inp8"  value="">
        <input type="text"  id="inp9"  value="">
        <input type="text"  id="inp10"  value="">
        <input type="text"  id="inp11"  value="">
        <input type="text"  id="inp12"  value="">        
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help,, is it possible when the user hovers over the value he selectedon the row, the background color changes to green and it matches to the respective background color of green on the table .

Comment: ,, Currently the table has a background color of orange,, I want when the value on the row is hovered it changes to green and also it also changes on the td on the table on the left side ..

Answer (score 2):

use this (handler for every td)

https://jsfiddle.net/xb5140po/

```
// code to read selected table row cell data (values).
        $("td").on('click',function(){

            alert(this.innerHTML);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#table1 td").on('click',function(){
   console.log($(this).text());
});
```